# pipenv install using previously downloaded packages

Tags: pip, pipenv

Say you regularly use a large python dependency like tensorflow but you want to create siloed virtual environments for each separate project.

If I download and install tensorflow to my system using pip, is there a way to tell pipenv to use the previously downloaded dependency instead of doing a slow and high-bandwidth re-download per virtual environment I set up?

Comment: `pip` stores wheels in cache by default, so when you reinstall for the same platform and interpreter targets, the wheels will be taken from cache.